# Сравнение производительности рекурсии и циклов

Tags: java, рекурсия, производительность

Добрый день. Есть такой код:

```
public class PerfTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            func1(1000);
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
        System.out.println();
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            func2(1000);
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
    }
    public static int func1(int value){
        if(--value > 0)
            func1(value);
        return value;
    }
    public static int func2(int value){
        while(--value > 0);
        return value;
    }
}
```

на выходе имеем:

```
1650043101

1937118
```

за счет чего такая разница? Насколько я понимаю, при циклической обработке итерируемая переменная находится в регистрах процессора, а при рекурсии на каждый рекурсивный вызов метода в него передается копия значения переменной, которая берется из памяти. Так ли это? Спасибо за ответ(ы).

Comment: странный тест, оптимизатор должен был посмотреть, что значения из циклов и внутри функции никак не меняется и результат всегда один и тот же: возврат самого первого переданного значения уменьшенного на единицу, и выкинуть и рекурсию и цикл, оставив сам вызов функции типа в которой один return, либо вообще заинлайнить ее, увидеть что значение из функции нигде не используется, выкинуть это значение, увидеть два пустых цикла и выкинуть их

Comment: @Grundy джава вообще не умеет в оптимизацию рекурсии. Выкидывать функцию из самой себя / делать выводы на основе функции, которая сейчас анализируется, скорее всего тоже не умеет, это довольно специфичный случай.

Comment: @etki, это именно к java относится или к самой vm или какому-нибудь JIT тоже относится?

Comment: @Grundy к javac и немного к jit в hotspot. Шипилев как-то [разбирал такой случай у себя в блоге](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/java-scala-divided-we-fail/), где в числе прочего показал, что scala умеет делать хвостовую оптимизацию, а java - только инлайнить первый вызов из всей рекурсивной цепочки, и то уже в рантайме.

Comment: @etki, это печально :)

Comment: а попробуйте померить нормальным фреймворком - jmh, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто приведу [ассемблерные выкладки](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) в дополнение к удаленному ответу @Barmaley

```
; PerfTest.func1 (с2)
0x00007fc219111be0: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x14000],eax
0x00007fc219111be7: push   rbp
0x00007fc219111be8: sub    rsp,0x20           ;*synchronization entry
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@-1 (line 16)

0x00007fc219111bec: mov    ebp,esi
0x00007fc219111bee: dec    ebp                ;*iinc
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@0 (line 16)

0x00007fc219111bf0: test   ebp,ebp
0x00007fc219111bf2: jle    0x00007fc219111c04  ;*ifle
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@4 (line 16)

0x00007fc219111bf4: add    esi,0xfffffffe     ;*iinc
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@0 (line 16)
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)

0x00007fc219111bf7: test   esi,esi
0x00007fc219111bf9: jle    0x00007fc219111c04  ;*ifle
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@4 (line 16)
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)

0x00007fc219111bfb: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp],esi
0x00007fc219111bfe: nop
0x00007fc219111bff: call   0x00007fc219046420  ; OopMap{off=36}
                      ;*invokestatic func1
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)
                      ;   {static_call}
0x00007fc219111c04: mov    eax,ebp
0x00007fc219111c06: add    rsp,0x20
0x00007fc219111c0a: pop    rbp
0x00007fc219111c0b: test   DWORD PTR [rip+0x171c43ef],eax        # 0x00007fc2302d6000
                      ;   {poll_return}
0x00007fc219111c11: ret                       ;*invokestatic func1
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)
                      ; - PerfTest::func1@8 (line 17)
```

---

```
; PerfTest.func2 (с2)
0x00007fc9f110ed80: sub    rsp,0x18
0x00007fc9f110ed87: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rbp  ;*synchronization entry
                      ; - PerfTest::func2@-1 (line 21)

0x00007fc9f110ed8c: mov    eax,esi
0x00007fc9f110ed8e: dec    eax                ;*iinc
                      ; - PerfTest::func2@0 (line 21)

0x00007fc9f110ed90: test   eax,eax
0x00007fc9f110ed92: jle    0x00007fc9f110eda2
0x00007fc9f110ed94: add    esi,0xfffffffe
0x00007fc9f110ed97: test   esi,esi
0x00007fc9f110ed99: jle    0x00007fc9f110eda0
0x00007fc9f110ed9b: mov    eax,0x1
0x00007fc9f110eda0: dec    eax                ;*ifle
                      ; - PerfTest::func2@4 (line 21)

0x00007fc9f110eda2: add    rsp,0x10
0x00007fc9f110eda6: pop    rbp
0x00007fc9f110eda7: test   DWORD PTR [rip+0x16405253],eax        # 0x00007fca07514000
                      ;   {poll_return}
0x00007fc9f110edad: ret
```

Что это вообще показывает? Действительно, рекурсия никуда не делась, хотя здесь ее можно было бы легально оптимизировать - в первой выкладке инструкция call присутствует, а во второй нет, при этом, если я правильно трактую адреса, call ссылается не на этот же участок кода, а идет еще через какой-то код-прокси, который такой же инструкцией call или (маловероятней) jmp возвращается на код из выкладки (скорее всего, это код вызова метода у класса). Инструкция call является аналогом вызова метода, она осуществляет прыжок в другой участок кода, и помимо самого прыжка необходимо еще сохранить, куда нужно возвращаться, какое состояние было у процессора в этот момент (чтобы его потом восстановить), установить корректные указатели стека и base pointer, часть этого выполняется автоматически, часть является call convention и выполняется дополнительными инструкциями. Все это - достаточно дорогие операции по сравнению с остальной частью кода (простым декрементом, выполняющимся за одну инструкцию), чтобы они оказывали влияние на производительность. Кроме того, прыжки по коду дает дополнительные возможности для падения производительности: если небольшой кусок кода без рекурсии практически гарантированно попадает в кэш процессора и не подгружается постоянно из оперативной памяти, то код с рекурсией и прыжками по коду может вытесняться из быстрых кэшей процессора, что заставит тратить время еще и на его получение из более медленных кэшей или оперативной памяти - по сравнению с простым декрементом регистра это тоже будет заметно.

Отмечу, что это, на самом деле, крайне неэффективный способ измерения производительности - в таком режиме можно только сравнить количество и набор инструкций, которые выполняются за разное время. Такой подход полезен для того, чтобы докопаться до истины и низкоуровневых причин тормозов, однако ничего не гарантирует, что JVM на одной машине не будет компилировать код в иные инструкции. Конкретно в этом случае я просто подтверждаю гипотезу о том, что рекурсия никуда не делась (не самым эффективным способом) и даю некоторую почву для гипотез, да и вообще мне на самом деле просто хотелось уж как-нибудь поиграться с hsdis. Бонусом можно увидеть, что JIT JIT'ом, а откуда-то в выкладках повторяется декремент и тест значения - то ли PrintAssembly не совсем верные данные выдает, то ли в коде зачем-то дублируются операции.

P.S. Теперь кто-то просто обязан выложить и проанализировать байткод